# My datas in database are written as [object object] as displayed in the handlebar template in Node JS

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, json, express

What i am trying to do is send my node js datas from my database to a handlebar template. But it was displayed as [object Object] as i send it to a template. I dont know why the are read as an [object Object] even though in the request webpage my data are normally displayed.

I have tried there following: JSON.parsing, JSON.stringify, GSON.parsing and JSON.stringify for my data to test what would happen but the data would not be displayed while using these methods.

```
                        -------SERVER.JS-------------
app.use('/number',function(req, res){  // created an API which gets the MySQL data onto that certain web directory

db.query("SELECT * FROM qnumber",function(error,rows,fields){ //query the data with the function and its parameters


    if(value <= rows.length){    
       value++;
       const getNumber = rows[value].qNumberCount;
       console.log('array: '+value +' = '+ getNumber);  
       console.log(getNumber);
        res.render('index',{title: 'CIV Queueing System',getNumber});
    //    res.send(getNumber);
    }    
    else{
        console.log('Error in Query!');
        console.log(error); //display in the console the specific error
        }

    });

    });
                       -------index.handlebars-------------
<html>
 <head>
 <style>
  body{background: rebeccapurple;font-family: verdana;color: whitesmoke;padding: 30px;}
  h1{font-size: 48px; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 2px; text-align: center;}
  p{font-size: 16px;text-align: center;}
 </style>
 <h1>Queue Counts</h1><br>
 </head>
 <body class="text-center"> 
<script src="/reload/reload.js">     
    var stringJSON = JSON.stringify({{this}});
    var parseJSON = JSON.parse({{this}});
    var gsonParse = gson.parse({{this}});
    var gsonString = gson.stringify({{this}});
</script>
 This: {{this}}<br><br>
 stringGSON: {{gsonString}}<br><br>
 parseGSON: {{gsonParse}}<br><br>
 parseJSON: {{parseJSON}}<br><br>
 stringJSON: {{stringJSON}}<br><br>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are performing all the operations directly on `this`. `this` in JavaScript always points to an object. To get the properties' values of the object, you need to specify the property name.

For e.g., if your data from DB is in the format

```
{
 'foo':'bar',
 'fooObj':
 {
   'innerFoo' : 'innerBar'
 }
}
```

then, the following queries would give relevant results:

`this.foo` will give `bar`

`this.fooObj` will give `[Object][Object]`

`this.fooObj.innerFoo` will give `innerBar`

Comment: It worked all i did was change the This: {{this}}<br><br> to This: {{this.getNumber}}<br><br>. In order to specify what property to display in the index.handlebars.